# Is Rerise negated when Summoning an Eidolon?

Tags: final-fantasy-type-0-hd

I've got Rem to learn an skill which gives the party Rerise status however she seems to use it randomly. but i have been wondering that since my character is killed when i summon an Eidolon and when the Eidolon is unsummoned my character lays there as if they had died from regular combat, would they come back to life if i summoned when they have Rerise?

The reason why i havn't been able to try this myself is because i generally play as Queen because she is the strongest at the moment (Lv. 49 equipped a sword with ~50 attack which out classes everyone else), Rem gives the party Rerise at random times and generally i am in the middle of a mission or far away from Akademia doing tasks when Rem does give Queen Rerise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the topic for [Easy EXP Missions](http://www.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-type-0/Easy_EXP_Missions), the section **Eidolon Leveling** states that reraise will revive your unit when the Eidolon is dismissed

> This is also a perfect place to level some of the Eidolons. Shiva Eidolons will gain the most from these battles. Higher level Eidolons won't get the experience quick enough to level like the Shiva class can. The uncontrollable Eidolons will also prove difficult to level here. Ifrit class Eidolons will be ineffective here as they will only heal the Flans with their fire attacks.
>
> To begin have Rem available in your playable party. Assure that she has the abilities Undying Wish and Manalchemy maxed out and equipped to her for use. Once you have the required items head to the Waterway.
>
> Once there get to the large portion of the room and get your AG guage to full. This can be accomplished by a few good killsight strikes. Once full perform the Undying Wish ability. **Once you have the reraise effect summon the Eidolon as you normally would. Rem will be revived at the end of the Eidolon's time. You may repeat this process an infinite amount of times so long as you have AG to perform Undying Wish and get the reraise status.** Manalchemy is a good ability should you need to heal yourself if you get hit by enemies and run out of MP.